# trying to iterate through an Object array within a constructor

Tags: object, iteration

I am trying to iterate through this array of objects, but I keep getting "; expected" when I try and make a for loop to do so within the constructor.

public class EletronicStore {

```
public EletronicStore() {
        Object[] obj = new Object[9];

        Desktop d1 = new Desktop(3.5, 8, 500, false);
        Desktop d2 = new Desktop(3, 16, 250, true);
        Desktop d3 = new Desktop(4.3, 32, 500, true);
        Laptop l1 = new Laptop(3.1, 32, 500, true, 15);
        Laptop l2 = new Laptop(2.5, 8, 250, false, 13);
        Laptop l3 = new Laptop(3.0, 16, 250, true, 15);
        Fridge f1 = new Fridge(15.6, true, "Gray");
        Fridge f2 = new Fridge(10.5, false, "White");
        Fridge f3 = new Fridge(23, true, "Stainless Steel");

        obj[0] = d1.toString();
        obj[1] = d2.toString();
        obj[2] = d3.toString();
        obj[3] = l1.LaptoString();
        obj[4] = l2.LaptoString();
        obj[5] = l3.LaptoString();
        obj[6] = f1.FridgetoString();
        obj[7] = f2.FridgetoString();
        obj[8] = f3.FridgetoString();

        public void printStock(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){  \\ here it says ; expected
                System.out.println(obj[i]);
            }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to put the for loop?...show us the code that doesn't work.  Does the above code work without error?

Comment: here is the code with the for loop, my apologies. yes there seems to be no problems with the code until i try and create the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is not with the for loop, it is that you are defining a new function inside the constructor

If you remove the 'public void printStock() {' and its closing brace and leave the for loop as is, it should work as you expect.

If you need the printStock function it will have to be defined outside the constructor, but it will not have access to your object array which is defined in the local scope of the constructor.